# Full Expression for energy in damped harmonic oscillator

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction, harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

The equation of motion for a damped harmonic oscillator is
$$m \ddot{x}=-sx-r\dot{x}$$
where $s$ is Hooke's constant and $r$ is damping coefficient.

For Damped Harmonic motion,

$$x=Ae^{-pt}(\sin(wt+l))$$

Where $A,l$ are constants of integration, $p=r/2m$ and $w=\sqrt{s/m - p^2}$

The energy/work is defined as the line integral of a force, thus

$$E=\int m\ddot{x}\,dx =\frac 12 m\dot{x}^2=-\frac 12sx^2-r\int\dot{x}\, dx+C$$

Now the integral

$$r\int\dot{x}\, dx=r\int\dot{x}^2\,dt =\dfrac{\mathrm{e}^{-2pt}\cdot\left(pw\sin\left(2wt+2l\right)+p^2\cos\left(2wt+2l\right)-w^2-p^2\right)}{4p}+C'$$

This term is often left in books and for example from [this](https://www.entropy.energy/scholar/node/damped-harmonic-oscillator-energy) website.

So is their analysis incomplete or am I doing something wrong?

Edit: Even the [graphs](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vv4hzfeavu) are very different

Comment: Please indicate the limits for each of the integrations.

Comment: @Farcher I added constants of integration, thanks for pointing the error out

Comment: So what happens when you include the constant of integration?

Comment: @Farcher you get information about initial conditions?

Comment: So what are the initial condition when using your method?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Energy of the system is usually defined as sum of kinetic and potential energy, here $E = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2}sx^2$. When the damping term is removed from the equation, this quantity with units of work is constant in time.

Comment: @JánLalinský https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy#Scientific_use. I want to figure out under what appropriate conditions we can neglect the last integral that I wrote.

Comment: But why? What is your motivation for writing that integral? This is not how energy expression is derived.

Comment: Wikipedia is a horrible source on physics, better learn from a textbook.

Comment: @JánLalinský "the integral $\int F\cdot dr$ is called work..." - Kleppner and Kolenkow

Comment: Yes, work. Not energy.